# Upgrade a partially Downgraded Moto G4 Plus (XT1644) with unlocked bootloader to Nougat

Tags: updates, rom-flashing, bootloader-lock, downgrade, motorola-moto-g-4g

tl;dr: had a problem rooting on Android N, flashed stock M image. Now running unrooted M, but attempts to OTA upgrade to N fail. I'm unable to relock bootloader by reflashing stock. I think this is because Motorola doesn't want users to downgrade. How can I get back up to N?

For the past year I've been using Android 6.0.1 rooted on my Moto G4 Plus (XT1644), the US retail model. This weekend I wanted to upgrade to Android 7.0 and install the security patches.

I made backups of my phone using FlashFire (standard and fastboot), then followed [this guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g4-plus/how-to/relock-bootloader-t3459333) to return my phone to stock and relock the bootloader. It worked, and I was able to OTA update to Android N and install the latest security updates.

I still wanted root, so I unlocked the bootloader again, booted into TWRP, and flashed the Magisk zip. After doing this, the phone would not boot except to recovery.

Here's where I screwed up. I figured I could just start again, and tried to flash the same 6.0.1 stock image. It worked, and the phone is now running 6.0.1, but is unable to install OTA updates. Further, when I try to flash stock and relock the bootloader, fastboot warns me
`(bootloader) Invalid signed image
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed`
for most steps, and `(bootloader) Still require signed boot.img` when I attempt to `fastboot oem lock`. The same happens when I try to restore my FlashFire backup. I believe this is functionality to prevent users from downgrading, although I was able to revert to 6.0.1.

I can't find a stock Android N rom for XT1644, just an OTA udpate I'm unable to install. What steps can I take to get back to Android N, or to completely revert my phone to stock so I can upgrade again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update to Nougat by downloading [stock firmware](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=673368273298955218) and flashing it via fastboot. For full guide go to this [xda thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g4-plus/how-to/moto-g4-plus-xt1640-43-athene-npj25-93-t3549369).

Method and files will work for XT1640/XT1641/XT1642/XT1643/XT1644.

> fastboot flash boot boot.img
>
> fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
>
> fastboot flash dsp adspso.bin
>
> fastboot flash oem oem.img
>
> fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.0
>
> fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.1
>
> fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.2
>
> fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.3
>
> fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.4
>
> fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.5
>
> fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.6
>
> fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.7
>
> fastboot flash modem NON-HLOS.bin
>
> fastboot erase modemst1
>
> fastboot erase modemst2
>
> fastboot flash fsg fsg.mbn
>
> fastboot erase cache
>
> fastboot erase userdata
> fastboot erase customize (optional: will erase any customizations if ordered through motomaker)
>
> fastboot erase clogo (optional: will erase the custom boot logo if ordered through motomaker)
>
> fastboot oem lock
>
> fastboot reboot

As you stated in the question that you are unable to run `fastboot oem lock begin` so skip this command and you will update to android N with an unlocked bootloader.

Comment: Thanks Deepak. Is that link for the XT1644? Don't see that model number anywhere, but there's a few hits when I unzip the folder and grep it.

Comment: @D.Stewart yes it is for XT1644. you can see this in xda thread